# Match the content of sentence/sequence in python

Tags: python, nlp, sequence, sentence, difflib

Suppose we 2 sequence of words

```
sentence1 = 'Ram is eating'

sentence2 = 'is Ram  eating'

sentence3 = 'is Ram playing'

sentence4 = 'movie Ram watching is'
```

how to get match% of such 2 sequences .
`difflib sequenceMatcher` matches letter by letter . Any way to find match % in these cases.

match% between sentence1 and sentence2 = `3/3 i.e. 100%`

match% between sentence1 and sentence3 = `2/3 i.e. 66.66%`

match% between sentence1 and sentence4 = `2/3 i.e. 66.66%`

```
match% = (number of words matching in sentence1 and sentence2 irrespective of position/total number of words in sentence1)*100
```

Comment: please define match %, what is it?

Comment: @svfat i have make edit with example hope that clears the match%

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about converting string to list and find matching percentage.

```
sentence1 = 'Ram is eating'
sentence2 = 'is Ram  eating'

sentence1 = sentence1.split()
sentence2 = sentence2.split()

longest = max(sentence1, sentence2, key=len)

per = len(set(sentence1) & set(sentence2))  
result = per/len(longest)
print (f'{result *100}% matched')
```

Gives #

```
100.0% matched
```

### Case 2

```
sentence1 = 'Ram is eating' 
sentence2 = 'is Ram'

sentence1 = sentence1.split()
sentence2 = sentence2.split()
longest = max(sentence1, sentence2, key=len)

per = len(set(sentence1) & set(sentence2))
result = per/len(longest)
print (f'{result *100}% matched')
```

Gives #

```
66.66666666666666% matched
```

### Case 3

```
sentence1 = 'Ram is eating'

sentence2 = 'is Ram'
sentence3 = 'is Ram playing'

sentence1 = sentence1.split()
sentence2 = sentence2.split()
sentence3 = sentence3.split()


longest = max(sentence1, sentence3, key=len)

per = len(set(sentence1) & set(sentence3)) 
result = per/len(longest)
print (f'{result *100}% matched')
```

Gives #

```
66.66666666666666% matched
```

Comment: made a case 3 with changing a word , where one word is changed then in that case this approach will fail .

Comment: Can you say that example? I don't get it changing word?...Can give some example like what should be sentence 1 and sentence 2

Comment: i have defined sentence 3 in the post can you please check that and thanks for your response

Comment: Ahh got it..You need to take length of biggest sentence...Updating right know

Comment: @k_p case 4 is wrong...It's 2/4 not 2/3

Comment: @k_p have tried?..Deos logic fits all cases?